# How to make a java model for a json file which constructed with to arrays?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file as below and I want to build a java model for that, but I could not find how. I tried to use online sites but unfortunately, they are not working in this JSON file, I appreciate it if anyone helps.

```
[
  [
    1598486400000,
    11758.83,
    11758.83,
    11350.75,
    11465
  ],
  [
    1598832000000,
    11300.4,
    11701,
    11300.4,
    11701
  ],
  [
    1599091200000,
    11672.32,
    11895.23,
    11418.25,
    11418.25
  ],
  [
    1599436800000,
    10197.46,
    10484.47,
    10177.79,
    10260.02
  ],
  [
    1599782400000,
    10359.45,
    10359.45,
    10125.01,
    10342.16
  ]
]
```

Comment: That is just a `List<List<Number>>`

Comment: @luk2302 this won't work, in the OPs requirement, there are no keys that can be assigned to the object `List<List<Number>>`

Comment: the problem is, I can not reach inner values after parsing.

Comment: What library are you using for JSON parsing? Please edit the question to add details, including any code that you've tried and the errors you've received, and a tag for the JSON library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

but you have to do parsing one item by one!

```
class Item {
  long id;
  ArrayList<double> values;
}

class All {
 ArrayList<Item> values;
}
```

Comment: you have to implement a good mapping from your json to this model